# Filter with nested element and scope AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter

Not too sure what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to return the participant of a conversation that has a username equal to the current user. Those are the scopes in the view:

```
conversation: [{id: 1, 
                participants: [{
                  date: 1234, 
                  user: [{
                      username: "test001", 
                      id: 2}],
                  },
                  {
                  date: 1456, 
                  user: [{
                      username: "test005", 
                      id: 5}],
                  }]
                }]
 user: [{username: "test001",
         id: 2}]
```

When calling {{user.username}} it works (no worries on that the scopes are loaded)
Here is the code in the html with the filter:

```
        <div class="list">
            <a ng-repeat="conversation in conversations"> 
                <div ng-repeat="notMe in conversation.participants | filter:{user: [{ username: user.username }] }">

                  {{notMe}}

                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

I wanted to avoid building a specific filter and was under the impression that the angular ones should handle that right?
Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Ended up using ng-if for the time being but it would be great to understand the issue with my filter :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="notMe in conversation.participants | filter:{user: { username: user.username } }">
```

Removed the [ ] and it works.